# Errors in LaTeX source

Tags: errors, koma-script

I keep getting this error when I try to compile my tex file.

Here's my tex file:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Create horizontal rule command with 1 argument of height

\title{ 
\normalfont \normalsize 
\textsc{NSIT, Division of Computer Engineering} \\ [25pt] % Your university, school and/or department name(s)
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] % Thin top horizontal rule
\huge Project Synopsis \\ % The assignment title
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Thick bottom horizontal rule
}

\author{
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        Ashish Kothari (240/CO/12)\\
        Ayush Gupta (248/CO/12)\\
        Chandan Kar (252/CO/12)\\
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]} % Your name
\date{\normalsize\today} % Today's date or a custom date

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Print the title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PROBLEM 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Fast \& light console-based Music Player}

The project aims to build a fast, light, and high-quality music player that is console-based with a simple and easy-to-use GUI written on shell scripts made for Linux systems. The music player is being designed to be able to decode most modern audio file formats. 

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Utility Requirements}

The utility requires very little computing power to function and is very efficient with CPU usage. For Linux OS, the utility has about 3\% to 4\% CPU usage on playing a high quality VBR MP3 on a Pentium 366MHz machine.\\

Requirements are listed as below:
\begin{itemize}
    \item mpg123 - an MPEG player and decoder library
    \item A Linux OS distribution
    \item Atleast 100MHz of computing power 
\end{itemize}


%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Innovativeness \& Usefulness}

The music player is being developed with the goal of optimising CPU utilisation, while having an easy-to-use GUI to play high quality music.\\

Some proposed features of the utility are:
\begin{itemize} \itemsep 1pt

    \item Support for various audio sub-systems 
    \item Simple but powerful control modes for frontend GUI
    \item Support for playback through URL
    \item Support for music playback from Cloud storage 
    \item Many audio data settings: resampling, choose channel, mono.
    \item Support for Relative Volume Adjustment / Replay Gain 

\end{itemize}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection {Current status of development}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt

    \item Basic functionality of the music player  has been achieved. 
    \item Frontend user interface is under development and is being developed using Zenity/ncurses library.
    \item Integration of proposed features into the GUI user interface of the utility has been started.

\end{itemize}

%------------------------------------------------

% \paragraph{Heading on level 4 (paragraph)}

% \lipsum[6] % Dummy text

% %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% % PROBLEM 2
% %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% \section{Lists}

% %------------------------------------------------

% \subsection{Example of list (3*itemize)}
% \begin{itemize}
%   \item First item in a list 
%       \begin{itemize}
%       \item First item in a list 
%           \begin{itemize}
%           \item First item in a list 
%           \item Second item in a list 
%           \end{itemize}
%       \item Second item in a list 
%       \end{itemize}
%   \item Second item in a list 
% \end{itemize}

% %------------------------------------------------

% \subsection{Example of list (enumerate)}
% \begin{enumerate}
% \item First item in a list 
% \item Second item in a list 
% \item Third item in a list
% \end{enumerate}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:90: LaTeX Error: Command \@BCOR already defined. [...fter\@@BCOR\CurrentOption BCORBCOR\@@BCOR}]

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:91: LaTeX Error: Command \@@BCOR already defined. [\newcommand*{\@@BCOR}{}]

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:99: LaTeX Error: Command \@DIV already defined. [...andafter\@@DIV\CurrentOption DIVDIV\@@DIV}]

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:100: LaTeX Error: Command \@@DIV already defined. [\newcommand*{\@@DIV}{}]

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:196: LaTeX Error: Command \x@paper already defined. [}]

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty:197: LaTeX Error: Command \x@@paper already defined. [\newcommand*{\x@@paper}{}]

There were also warnings.

[no file]: LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):    [fontsize=11pt].
(Log parsing issues. Disregard unless something else is wrong.)

[Done!]
```

Also, I installed TeXLive using the backports ppa recently on my Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Did you try making a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and post the `shortest-possible-simple-code` to get a `reproducible error` while posting MWE.

Comment: You can delete some package, or some part of the document, and recompile, and see if the problem persists. That way, you can really find where the problem is, which will encourage TeX.SX users to help… giving us the Minimal Working Example texenthusiast linked.

Comment: Please install vanilla TeXLive, which contains the latest version of KOMA-Script. And please read the koma manual for e.g. titlepage design.

Comment: Same here. I have TeXLive 2013 and I compiled in the terminal in Ubuntu 13.10 and I was able to generate the same pdf as the first answer. There are no issues with the code as such. But there are some unnecessary packages, one such being `lipsum`

Comment: -1 is enough don't do beyond since the message of "make an effort to build MWE" is passed. @Ashish Please have a look at [\listfiles and Updating TeX distro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to avoid downvoting in future.

Comment: Some times such messages are due to old versions of .aux and such temporary files laying around. Clean up and try again.

Comment: @texenthusiast The problem is that now this question has +3 votes, which is anything but justified.

Answer (score 9):

Probably you have an out-to-date KOMA-Script bundle and that's why you get those errors.

Apart from that, try to avoid using `fancyhdr` with KOMA classes, since it is not recommended.

You can use the package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is designed to work with such classes.

So, you can replace the lines

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % Makes all pages in the document conform to the custom headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % No page header - if you want one, create it in the same way as the footers below
\fancyfoot[L]{} % Empty left footer
\fancyfoot[C]{} % Empty center footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % Page numbering for right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header underlines
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove footer underlines
```

with simply

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

If you have an old version of KOMA-Script, replace

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
```

with

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document - comment this line to return to the LaTeX default
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % Customize the height of the header

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % Number equations within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{figure}{section} % Number figures within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)
\numberwithin{table}{section} % Number tables within sections (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4)

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Removes all indentation from paragraphs - comment this line for an assignment with lots of text

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Create horizontal rule command with 1 argument of height

\title{
\normalfont \normalsize
\textsc{NSIT, Division of Computer Engineering} \\ [25pt] % Your university, school and/or department name(s)
\horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm] % Thin top horizontal rule
\huge Project Synopsis \\ % The assignment title
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Thick bottom horizontal rule
}

\author{
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        Ashish Kothari (240/CO/12)\\
        Ayush Gupta (248/CO/12)\\
        Chandan Kar (252/CO/12)\\
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]} % Your name
\date{\normalsize\today} % Today's date or a custom date

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Print the title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PROBLEM 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Fast \& light console-based Music Player}

The project aims to build a fast, light, and high-quality music player that is console-based with a simple and easy-to-use GUI written on shell scripts made for Linux systems. The music player is being designed to be able to decode most modern audio file formats.

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Utility Requirements}

The utility requires very little computing power to function and is very efficient with CPU usage. For Linux OS, the utility has about 3\% to 4\% CPU usage on playing a high quality VBR MP3 on a Pentium 366MHz machine.\\

Requirements are listed as below:
\begin{itemize}
    \item mpg123 - an MPEG player and decoder library
    \item A Linux OS distribution
    \item Atleast 100MHz of computing power
\end{itemize}


%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Innovativeness \& Usefulness}

The music player is being developed with the goal of optimising CPU utilisation, while having an easy-to-use GUI to play high quality music.\\

Some proposed features of the utility are:
\begin{itemize} \itemsep 1pt

    \item Support for various audio sub-systems
    \item Simple but powerful control modes for frontend GUI
    \item Support for playback through URL
    \item Support for music playback from Cloud storage
    \item Many audio data settings: resampling, choose channel, mono.
    \item Support for Relative Volume Adjustment / Replay Gain

\end{itemize}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection {Current status of development}
\begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt

    \item Basic functionality of the music player  has been achieved.
    \item Frontend user interface is under development and is being developed using Zenity/ncurses library.
    \item Integration of proposed features into the GUI user interface of the utility has been started.

\end{itemize}

%------------------------------------------------

% \paragraph{Heading on level 4 (paragraph)}

% \lipsum[6] % Dummy text

% %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% % PROBLEM 2
% %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% \section{Lists}

% %------------------------------------------------

% \subsection{Example of list (3*itemize)}
% \begin{itemize}
%   \item First item in a list
%       \begin{itemize}
%       \item First item in a list
%           \begin{itemize}
%           \item First item in a list
%           \item Second item in a list
%           \end{itemize}
%       \item Second item in a list
%       \end{itemize}
%   \item Second item in a list
% \end{itemize}

% %------------------------------------------------

% \subsection{Example of list (enumerate)}
% \begin{enumerate}
% \item First item in a list
% \item Second item in a list
% \item Third item in a list
% \end{enumerate}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apart from all the other hints: `paper=a4` and `fontsize=11pt` are the defaults anyway, and could therefore be left out.

Comment: Still getting the same errors.

Comment: Install Vanilla TeX Live. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/27635

Answer (score 3):

I've just taken a look at your code and it seems to compile perfectly normally in TexMaker.  This is the output I got using your code with no changes:

[image]

[image]

Is this what you were expecting?  I've tried sticking your code into the [Writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com) website for a live preview and it works fine too.  Try the [Write a new paper](https://www.writelatex.com/docs?template=paper) link, delete the template code and add your own to see for yourself.